# Setting a javascript variable to margins

Tags: javascript

How do I make the left margin a variable so that I can make it change dynamically on the keydown of the arrows

I'm trying to make the div called tank move.

Code:

```
function moveTank() {
  var tank = document.getElementById("tank");
  var tankLeft = tank.style.margin-left;    
}

moveTank();
```

Comment: CSS style properties with dash are camelCase in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

```
var tankLeft = tank.style.marginLeft;
```

Note: It will work only for inline specified margin - `<img id="tank" src="..." style="margin-left:10px">`

And why not to use `position:absolute` with `left` and `top` for your tank sprite?

```
<div id="tankfield" style="position:relative">
  <img id="tank" src="..." style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px">
</div>
<script>
  var tankX=0, tankY=0;
  function placeTank() {
    var tank = document.getElementById("tank");
    tank.style.left = tankX+'px';
    tank.style.top  = tankY+'px';
  }
  // ...
  function tankDown() {
    tankY += 5;
    placeTank();
  }
  // ...
</script>
```

Comment: Just tried this and then tried alert(tankLeft) which shows up blank.  Is this something I have done wrong with the alert or something I have done wrong in the code?

Comment: It depends where the style is set. The following will work for inline styles only.

Comment: you first need to set the value if it is not set already inline

Comment: I have set the style within CSS.  I can go about setting it in JavaScript though, I suppose how it's best to be done for what I'm doing?

Comment: `tank.style.marginLeft = "0px";`

Answer (score 0):

Hyphenated style attributes get camelCased in js, so you want `tank.style.marginLeft`.

Also note that 
1) That method will only read style attributes set directly on the element, not those in a stylesheet, and
2) it will be a string, either "" or else something like "123px"

Answer (score 0):

why are you using margin? just move the tank with left/top position:

try `tank.css({left: "-=10px"});`

Comment: Where does OP mention jQuery?